# Can I modify vertex buffer in GPU through the vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, gpu, shader

For some reason cannot find the answer on the web. I want to update vertex attributes in GPU through the shader in similar form:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform mat4 someTransformation;

void main()
{
    position = position * someTransformation;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: *"Can I modify vertex buffer in GPU through the vertex shader?"* - No you can not. `position` is an input variable. There is no concept of writing vertices back to the buffer. However, you can use [Transform Feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback) to generate new primitives.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you. That clarifies a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you write the code you have written? Yes, that is legal code.

Will that change the contents of any GPU storage? No.

While there are [ways for a VS to directly manipulate the contents of a buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object), if the buffer region being manipulated is also potentially being used as an attribute array for a rendering command, then you will have undefined behavior.

You can use SSBOs to manipulate *other* storage which is not being used as the input for rendering. And you can use [transform feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback) to accumulate data output from vertex processing. But you cannot have a VS directly modify its own input array.